# AWS: How could I programatically add IAM Roles to the EC2 instances that are generated from a Launch Template in Auto-Scaling Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-roles

I'm quite new to AWS and I have this issue that I'm confused about: basically we are trying to add AWS Cloudwatch logging to our EC2 instances. I was able to set it up on Staging instance with manually adding IAM Role for Cloudwatch and running those commands described in this [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html). It made logging work. And then I was able to set it up for our currently active production EC2 instances also adding those rules and running those commands from that article in CLI while connected to the instance via SSH.

The problem, however, is that there are new production instances being generated each time we redeploy our app to production. Unlike the Staging, where simply pull latest changes and run commands to restart Docker, and the EC2 instance is always running and it's always same. Production instances are being generated using a Launch Template. Basically, I create an AMI image of Staging instance, then update the Launch Template to use the latest AMI, then I run instance refresh for the auto-scaling group that uses that Launch Template, which terminates old production EC2 instances and creates the new ones.

But instead of applying those roles and running those commands manually each time to those newly created production EC2 instances I would like to set it up to be applied automatically each time they are being generated since after I do that I no longer see the IAM Roles attached to those new production instances and logging fails. Could you tell me please how could I set it up to have those roles and any necessary configurations applied to the newly generated production EC2 instances?

**UPDATE:**

I tried changing "User Data" of the Launch Template to those 2 options, however in (1) case it just didn't attach any role and logging failed and in (2) case auto-scaling would fail:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you check `IAM instance profile` in your `launch template` -> `Advanced details`? Can you show what do you have there?

Comment: As @Riz said set the profile in the advance section of the launch template you can also add user data script that will run every time a new instance is set up, this is under the same advance section.

Comment: I updated the question with the details of the "User Data" config